# Displaying X programs on remote systems

Tags: x11, remote, display

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and Fedora 20 as a test environment. I am trying to send X programs from Fedora to Ubuntu through an SSH session. My setup is as follows:

On Ubuntu ran:

```
Xhost +IP Address of Fedora
```

This returns:

```
10.10.24.153 being added to access control list
```

From the Fedora system I then run:

```
DISPLAY=10.10.25.168:0.0
```

This step redirects Fedora's Display to the Ubuntu system.

Then I ssh to Fedora from Ubuntu. At this point when I try to launch a program, such as gedit from the ssh prompt I get this: (and no gedit window appears)

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused (gedit:7358): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

HOWEVER, when I launch gedit directly from Fedora it appears on my Ubuntu system, albeit errors on the Fedora side:

```
** (gedit:7372): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-77RFAr0MHI: Connection refused
```

I should be able to launch the X based program from the ssh session and it appear on screen. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run the X apps over your `ssh` session you just need to tell `ssh` to carry the traffic. Don't run `xhost` and don't override `DISPLAY`.

```
ssh -Yf remote-host some-x-application
```

The `-Y` flag tells `ssh` to create a `DISPLAY` environment variable on the `remote-host` and carry the resulting traffic across the encrypted connection. The `-f` flag tells `ssh` to do all this in the background so that it looks like the session has terminated immediately.

If you prefer to have an interactive shell visibly running on the end of the `ssh` connection you can also do this sort of thing:

```
ssh -Y remote-host
...log in as necessary...

some-x-application &
another-x-application &
...etc...

wait; exit
```

Comment: Ok, that works, but is not exactly what I was hoping for. And actually, after re-reading the documentation I was following earlier, It does appear that I have to start the X app on the remote side first, which seems somewhat counterintuitive :/ but thanks for the tip!

Comment: @user53029 where else would you expect to start the application?

Comment: From the ssh or telnet session on the "client/local" side. Use case being I have a low end system that can connect remotely to a server class system and consume its resources rather than mine for running apps however like I said after re-reading the documentation I think the app must be started from the "remote" side.

Comment: @user53029 that's exactly what you do. Log on to the client. `ssh` to the server and run your application.

Comment: I understand. However if I run ssh -Yf <remote host> /usr/bin/firefox or whatever it brings the browser over but then closes the connection. Is there a way to keep it open and run more apps if needed or do I just keep starting up ssh tunnels? I am not aware of a way to do this with SSH which is why I was hoping the "xhost/display" method would work for me.

Comment: @user53029. Yes. That's what the `-f` flag does (see the man page for details). I'll update the Answer to show an alternative

Comment: Don't override `DISPLAY` = GENIUS. Slams head on table and goes to sleep. Finally got it working.